# how to set a responsive SVG width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I was wondering if it is possible to make selected SVG path (marked in blue) responsive.
Ideally, I would like to set the **blue path width to 100%** and have the **other paths surround it so it forms the letter "U"**. It would be great if the `letter-wrap`'s height determines the height of the SVG letter.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/dpezfbm6/)

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/J8sPs/26/) is sort of a simplified version of what I would like to achieve functionally.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want the height to change when the window resizes?

Comment: Hi @chipChocolate.py -- Not quite, I'm thinking since the height isn't set final, I want to use the letter-wrap to determine the height and width (ex: height: 10%; width: auto; would make the letter small)

Comment: I might answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27070929/3905567), since that's exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py -- Would be amazing if you can! Since there hasn't been an answer, I've been trying to solve it myself the whole day but I'm not getting too far...

Comment: Will try my best and come up with a solution as soon as possible.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py -- Amazing! Would tremendously be appreciated! Would it be better if we enter a chat room so I can provide you more code / resources?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question well. At first your svg image vieBow should be the same size as containing image. Svg image has to have width and height in svg code to be correct in MSIE (http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/svg-as-image.html) . To obtain such behaviour split it into 3 images. Middle one set as repeat-x svg background converted to base 64. Is this what you are looking for? 
http://jsfiddle.net/dpezfbm6/3/ 
`<div class="wrapper">
    <svg class="float"></svg>
    <div class="floatsvgbackgroundrepeat-x"></div>
    <svg class="float"></svg>
</div>`